# MVP - java.lang.NullPointerException: access database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm starting to study Android and I'm trying to develop an app. I'm with some difficulties like save data in database.

I structured the app using the MVP pattern (model view presenter). In the View I have some fields (code and text for example) that I wanna save in database.

View

```
public class PostView extends Fragment {

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    PostPresenterImpl postPresenterImpl = new PostPresenterImpl(getActivity());

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, null);

    id_server = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    content = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    id_search = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ...

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText("");
            PostModel postModel = new PostModel();
            postModel.setIdServer(Integer.parseInt(id_server.getText().toString()));
            postModel.setContent(content.getText().toString());
            System.out.println("setOnClickListener");
            //postPresenterImpl.setContext(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            postPresenterImpl.addPost(postModel);
            //list = postPresenterImpl.getAllStudentsList();
            //tv.setText(postPresenterImpl.print(list));
        }
    });
```

Presenter

```
public class PostPresenterImpl implements PostPresenter {


   private Context context;

   public PostPresenterImpl(Context c){
       context = c;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean addPost(PostModel postModel) {
       Post post = new Post(context);
       System.out.println("postModel " + postModel.getIdServer());
       System.out.println("postModel " + postModel.getContent());
       System.out.println("postModel " + postModel.getTimeStamp());
       System.out.println("PostPresenterImpl - addPost");
       post.addPostDetail(postModel);
       return true;
   }
```

Model

```
public class Post extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements Common {

    public static String TAG = "tag_post";

    private Context context;

    public PostPresenterImpl(Context c){
    context = c;
}

    public Post(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // assigning context Change your constructor
        this.context = context;
    }

    public long addPostDetail(PostModel postModel) {
         System.out.println("addPostDetail");

         SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
         // Creating content values
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(KEY_IDSERVER, postModel.getIdServer());
         values.put(CONTENT, postModel.getContent());
         // insert row in post table
         long insert = db.insert(TABLE_POST, null, values);
         return insert;
     }
```

After execute the app and fill the filds on the screen, a excpetion is launched:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
```

On PostPresenterImpl class I'm printing the values of the objetct and this is okay. Anny sugest, plis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PostPresenterImpl postPresenterImpl = new PostPresenterImpl(getActivity());
```

Move this initialization to `onAttach()` or later in the fragment lifecycle. At instance initialization phase the fragment isn't yet attached to an activity and `getActivity()` returns `null`.

The exception you're seeing is caused by a `null` passed in for a `Context` to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a separate **Contract** class that makes your DB creation or something like that? Because you're trying to access the db and in you code I couldn't see the creation command.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tablename ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ... ");
```

I[Here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html) you have an excellent article talking about managing correctly the DB on Android.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I've created the database, thanks for the article and for help